# Ember.js - change the format of a network request sent when getting a model's related objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I am trying to make my network calls between my Ember app and my Rails API backend more efficient when fetching an ember data object's related objects. Let's say I have two models:

- `shop` - a `shop` has many `products`
- `product` - a `product` belongs to a `shop`

I am using a `RESTAdapter` for both of these models, so if I try to get a shop's products like so:

```
let shop = this.store.find("shop", 1);
let products = shop.get("products");
```

Let's assume I have a `shop` with a `hasMany` relationship to the first 500 `product`s in my database. The network requests will look something like this (assume all url paths are valid and lead to valid controllers and actions):

```
localhost:3000/api/v1/shops/1
localhost:3000/api/v1/products/1
localhost:3000/api/v1/products/2
localhost:3000/api/v1/products/3
localhost:3000/api/v1/products/4
localhost:3000/api/v1/products/5
...
```

My `products` api endpoint can take in a `filter` parameter to feed into an `ApplicationRecord.where` call. So what I'd really like to do is to be able to change the outcome of the `shop.get("products")` call so it makes a single call to my `products` endpoint with a filter parameter and gets all related products in bulk, instead of 500 individual calls to the api endpoint.

Is there an established pattern for doing this?

Comment: this might help: https://discuss.emberjs.com/t/coalescing-find-requests/7076

Comment: so basicly in your adapter add this line: `coalesceFindRequests: true,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a pattern/a parameter for that.
It's called `coalesceFindRequests` and would be set in your application adapter:

```
// app/adapters/application.js

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    coalesceFindRequests: true,
    // more params to be set here
});
```

related links:
[The Adapter Docs](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember-data/2.14/classes/DS.Adapter/properties/coalesceFindRequests?anchor=coalesceFindRequests)
[an emberjs docs-entry](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember-data/2.14/classes/DS.RESTAdapter/methods/buildURL?anchor=urlForFindMany)
[a forum entry](https://discuss.emberjs.com/t/coalescing-find-requests/7076)

Comment: Thank you so much! I had a feeling it had to do with a custom adapter, but I was expecting to have to override a few functions. Glad to see it's a simple one-liner.